# reflexive zero-one matrix or matrix?

Tags: matrices

So, I learned in the class that of a zero-one matrix, if the number on cross line are all $1$, then the matrix is reflexive.

$\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0& 0\\
  0& 1& 0\\
  0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

However, when this comes to a more general matrix (not zero-one matrix), we often see matrix like this

$\begin{pmatrix}
  2& -1& 9\\
  3& 2& 9\\
  8& 7& 2
\end{pmatrix}$

or

$\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 2& 3\\
  -1& 0& 0\\
  7& 1& 4
\end{pmatrix}$

the cross line are other numbers instead of $0$, in these case, is the matrix still reflexive or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the matrix reflexive, the matrix is being used as a stand in to represent a relation.

If $m_{i,j} = 1$ then $a_i \sim a_j$ (or $a_i$ is related to $a_j$ ) where $a_i, a_j$ are the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ elements of some set.

and if $m_{i,j} = 0$ then $a_i \nsim a_j$ (or $a_i$ is not related to $a_j$)

All elements in this relation-matrix must equal $1$ or $0.$

A relation is reflexive if for all elements in that set $a_i \sim a_i$

General matrices are not representations of relations and cannot be described as reflexive or not reflexive.

Comment: So I tried different matrices on wolframalpha, it still recognized whether those matrices are symmetric or antisymmetric.In this case, why symmetric and antisymmetric are recognizable?   for example $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& -2& 3\\
  2& 0& -6\\
  -3& 6& 0
\end{pmatrix}$ is recognized as a antisymmetric matrix

Comment: I would call that "skew-symetric."  Anyway, a symmetric matrix can describe phenomena beyond relations.